# ASP.NET User Control - Build on Every Change

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, user-controls, development-environment

I am working on building a User Control Asp.net - VB.Net.

When we do any change to User Control Code we have to build the project to see the code change.

Since the project is huge take a long time to build - can you suggest any shorter or better way or tips that can reduce the project build on user control code change

Right now when I change any VB code , I need to build project and then go to page to see the code change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reduce the build time by doing a command line build. using msbuild - it was faster.

Additionally, I tweaked command to just build the web project only

```
msbuild EBR.Web.vbproj
```

Hope it helps someone else as well.